# Azure Document DB : Creation of a collection is throwing "DocumentClientException" with error message "Session token specified is invalid"

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, document-database

I am getting the below exception `"Microsoft.Azure.Documents.DocumentClientException: Message: {"Errors":["Session token specified is invalid."]}"`in the workflow which creates a collection with the given name if and only if there exists no collection with the specified name in the database. I am trying to execute this snippet from a worker role by calling `documentClient.CreateDocumentCollectionAsync`.

```
var documentCollection = new DocumentCollection
            {
                Id = "xyz",
            }
documentClient.CreateDocumentCollectionAsync(UriFactory.CreateDatabaseUri(dbName), documentCollection)
```

I have ensured that document db uri and key are specified correctly. 
Can anyone explain what is going on here?
I could not get much help from documentation.

Comment: Are you providing a session token or the `x-ms-session-token` header for the operation?

Comment: @NickChapsas I have not specified any session token.

Comment: @Nithin Hi, what's your application scenarios? It's hardly reproducing your issue on my side.Could you post more details to let me help you?

Comment: I have a console app that makes a call to document db for populating data.. I am running this directly on worker role vm by enabling remote desktop.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try specifiying a partition key? You should set this when creating collections.

```
var partitionKeyDefinition = new PartitionKeyDefinition();
partitionKeyDefinition.Paths.Add("/partitionKey");

var collectionDefinition = new DocumentCollection
{
    Id = collectionId,
    PartitionKey = partitionKeyDefinition 
};
```